# Get all the rows except for the fields Laravel: Excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel

So I have an excel file with a format like this

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to get all the rows below the `row1`

This would be the records of `John Doe` and `Mc Doe`

Currently I have this code from `controller`

```
    $dateTime = date('Ymd_His');
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $fileName = $dateTime . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $savePath = public_path('/upload/projectlist/');
    $file->move($savePath, $fileName);

    $excel = Importer::make('Excel');
    $excel->load($savePath.$fileName);
    $collection = $excel->getCollection();

    if(sizeof($collection[1]) == 5){

        for($row=1; $row<sizeof($collection); $row++){
            try{
                dd($collection[$row]);
            }
            catch(\Exception $e){
                return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->with(['errors'=>$e->getMessage()])
                ->with('modal',$modal);
            }
        }
    }else{
        return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->with(['errors'=> [0=> 'Please provide date in file according to your format.']])
        ->with('modal',$modal);
    }
```

And this gives me an output like this

[image]

Which the record of `John Doe` only. How can I get all the rows except for `row1`?

Comment: well the `dd` is killing the script so it will only get to the `dd` in the first iteration of that loop

Comment: if you had an array how would you remove the first element?

Comment: This is the current output if I use this `return $collection;`  
 `[["id","first_name","last_name","email","birthdate"],[1,"John","Doe","John Doe",{"date":"1996-09-07 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Taipei"}],[2,"Mc","Doe","Mc Doe",{"date":"1996-09-07 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Taipei"}]]`   Since the first array item is field. I need only to get the following array not including the field names

Answer (score 0):

here you get all the value if remove dd & it save every row in a array & dd that array outside the for loop then you get all results

Comment: I tried to used this one `return ($collection[$row]);` but I'm getting this record only `[1,"John","Doe","John Doe",{"date":"1996-09-07 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Taipei"}]` record for `John Doe` only not included the record of `Mc Doe`

Comment: @RaeIan if you do a return inside that loop you are ending that function ... so again it will only get to the return in the first iteration

Comment: I tried to do outside the loop and use this `return $collection;` the output is an array but the fields of the column is included.

Comment: @RaeIan of course because that is the whole collection from the Excel library

Comment: is it possible to get only the records without including the row of the field names?